# Is there any option in iOS app to adjust treble,bass and loud property of music running in another apps like SoundCloud?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

**MPVolumeView can be used to adjust volume. Please let me know if there is any option to adjust these sound properties.**

1. *treble*
2. *bass*
3. *loud*

Comment: "Loud" isn't a property of sound - are you referring to the system volume, or "[loudness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness)"? Or something else entirely?

Comment: No. There is no access to audio from other apps beyond the master system volume, and ducking (lowering their audio when you're playing).

Comment: you might want to check CoreAudio https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio

Comment: Yes I mean "loudness".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview) the answer is no, and I would steer away from undocumented functions etc.

> MPVolumeView
>
> A slider control used to set the system audio output volume, and a button for choosing the audio output route.

If you want to do that, I think you will need to work with some more advanced libraries, see this [example code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/equalizing_audio_with_vdsp) from Apple.